# What is a word for a "phrase to remember", e.g. "Life is like a box of chocolates"?

Tags: single-word-requests

> My mother always said, "Life is like a box of chocolates."

How do you describe such phrases, i.e., a phrase/saying/quote to remember by?

Something like a *memento* or *reminder*, but for "phrases", "sayings" or "motivational quotes". "Reminder" may be a good word, but I wonder if there is something better, like "self-reminder".

Comment: This particular sentence is a metaphor, but I am referring to quotes that you keep in mind in general, for example, "Like MLK always said, "Injustice anywhere is a threat to justice everywhere.""

Comment: 'proverb, adage, aphorism, or axiom' given at the duplicate, with a link to other synonyms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The saying is categorised as a **proverb** on [Literary Terms](https://literaryterms.net/proverb/):

> In the movie Forrest Gump, the main
> character frequently speaks in
> proverbs, and is even shown inventing
> a few. For example:
>
> *Life is like a box of chocolates. You
> never know what you’re gonna get.*
>
> This proverb means that life is full
> of surprises and it is impossible to
> predict the future.

According to [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/proverb), a proverb is

> a short sentence, etc., usually known
> by many people, stating something
> commonly experienced or giving advice

Answer (score 1):

I think what might fit best here is [aphorism](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/aphorism), meaning

> A pithy observation that contains a general truth, such as, “if it ain't broke, don't fix it.”

Comment: "Aphorism" was my first thought too.

Answer (score 0):

It could be referred to as a ***proverb***, as niamulbengali notes in their [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/555473/390415).

For the sense ("self-reminder," as you say) of something one repeats often, it could also be a ***mantra***, [defined](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/mantra) as:

> an often repeated word, formula, or phrase, often a truism:
>
> *If I hear the “less is more” mantra one more time, I'll scream.*

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague and encompasses a large number of set phrases, quotations and clichés all of which have their own name/subcategory.

However: One phrase is "**an old saw**"

OED

> **old saw**  n. **a sententious saying, a homily; a traditional proverb or maxim; a homespun aphorism;**
>
> c1395   G. Chaucer Wife of Bath's Tale 660   *I sette noght an hawe Of his prouerbes nof his olde sawe.*
>
> 1857   N. Amer. Rev. July 169   *To clinch the argument with an old saw, is to come off with flying colors, in his own undisguised estimation.*
>
> 1992   Harper's Mag. Oct. 5/1   *Please spare me that old saw about a person ‘making his or her own opportunities’.*

Answer (score 0):

Aren't they called ***memorable phrases***?

I also found ***sound bite***. One of its definitions is:

> A group of words, often originating in popular culture that is spontaneously popularized after widespread repeated use.

[Here (Word Hippo)](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/sound_bite.html#C0-2) you can find a few synonyms of it like, **catchphrase** or **slogan**.